# MS Excel - How to format cell as Yes/No instead of TRUE/FALSE

Tags: excel

I use Epplus to export excel as following

```
        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"sample6.xlsx");
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
        {
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = true;
            ws.Cells["A2"].Value = false;
            pck.Save();
        }
```

The result excel show TRUE and FALSE

[image]

How can I show those cells as Yes/No

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use excel template with custom format **"Yes";;"No";**

[image: YesNo]

Then load that template and write 1/0 instead of True/False

```
        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"sample6.xlsx");
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
        {
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Content"];
            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = 1;
            ws.Cells["A2"].Value = 0;
            pck.Save();
        }
```

Comment: May be worth noting that this can also be used to color the cells based on their boolean value without needing to use conditional formats, e.g. `[GREEN]"Yes";;[RED]"No";`